# sort array of string numbers in ascending order and check sequence

Tags: javascript, sorting, duplicates, sequence

I want to sort array of string in ascending sequence without missing sequence and check for no duplicates

This is my function so far

```
const sortAndCheckSequence = async (value) => {
let data = [...value]; // suppose value is ['1','2','1.1','3','1.1.1','1.2','3.1']

sortedData = data.sort((a, b) => (a > b ? 1 : -1));

// sortedData ['1','1.1','1.1.1','1.2','2','3','3.1']

const CheckSequence = (sortedData) =>{

// check sequence return true if there is no missing sequence and no duplicates else return false
  }
 }

// assuming data is sorted
sortAndCheckSequence(['1','1.1','1.1.1','1.2','2','3','3.1']) // true
sortAndCheckSequence(['1','1.1','1.1.1','1.2','2','2.1','3','4','5']) // true
sortAndCheckSequence(['1','1.1','1.1.1','1.2','2','2.1','3','4','4.1','5','5.1.1']) // false '5.1' missing 
sortAndCheckSequence(['1','1.1','1.1.1','1.2','2','2.1','3','4','5','1.2']) // false '1.2' is duplicate
sortAndCheckSequence(['1','1.1','1.1.1','1.2','1.4','2','3','3.1']) // false '1.3' missing
sortAndCheckSequence(['1','1.1','1.1.1','1.1.2','1.2','1.4','2','2.1','9','3','3.1']) //false '9' is not in sequence
```

Comment: how do you define missing sequence? how do I suppose to know if there is or isn't a 2.1.1 between 2.1 and 3?

Comment: That the thing, you don't know for sure because the numbers are based on user input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a value `x.y.z`, there are only four possible values that can follow it:

- `x.y.z.1`
- `x.y.(z+1)`
- `x.(y+1)`
- `(x+1)`

Things become easier if we check each value by removing any prefix it has in common with the previous value:

- `x.y.z.1` truncates to `.1` (versus `""` – the entire previous value is the common prefix)
- `x.y.(z+1)` truncates to `(z+1)` (versus `z`)
- `x.(y+1)` truncates to `(y+1)` (versus `y.z`)
- `(x+1)` has no common prefix, so remains `(x+1)` versus `x.y.z`

So – we just need to check if each value is the previous one with `.1` appended, or if it has a common prefix with the next number incremented.

For bonus points we can detect duplicates separately, although it's not clear if you're interested in precise validation messages.

```js
const sortAndCheckSequence = (value) => {
  let data = [...value];

  sortedData = data.sort((a, b) => (a > b ? 1 : -1));

  const removeCommonPrefix = (a, b) => {
    const minLen = Math.min(a.length, b.length);

    let i = 0;
    while (i < minLen && a[i] === b[i]) ++i;

    return [a.substr(0, i), a.substr(i), b.substr(i)];
  }

  const FindError = (sortedData) => {
    for (let i = 1; i < sortedData.length; ++i) {
      const [prevValue, value] = [sortedData[i - 1], sortedData[i]];

      if (value === prevValue)
        return `Duplicate ${value}`;

      const [prefix, prevSuffix, suffix] = removeCommonPrefix(prevValue, value);

      if (prevSuffix === "") {
        if (suffix !== ".1")
          return `Expected ${prevValue}.1, got ${value}`;
      } else if (suffix !== String(parseInt(prevSuffix) + 1)) {
        return `Expected ${prefix}${parseInt(prevSuffix) + 1}, got ${value}`;
      }
    }
    return null; // no error
  }

  const error = FindError(sortedData);
  console.log(error || "No error");

  return error === null; // Does the sequence pass the check without any errors?
}

sortAndCheckSequence(['1', '1.1', '1.1.1', '1.2', '2', '3', '3.1']); // true
sortAndCheckSequence(['1', '1.1', '1.1.1', '1.2', '2', '2.1', '3', '4', '5']); // true
sortAndCheckSequence(['1', '1.1', '1.1.1', '1.1.1.1', '1.1.1.2', '1.2', '3', '3.1']); // false: 2 is missing
sortAndCheckSequence(['1', '1.1', '1.1.1', '1.2', '2', '2.1', '3', '4', '4.1', '5', '5.1.1']); // false '5.1' missing 
sortAndCheckSequence(['1', '1.1', '1.1.1', '1.2', '2', '2.1', '3', '4', '5', '1.2']); // false '1.2' is duplicate
sortAndCheckSequence(['1', '1.1', '1.1.1', '1.2', '1.4', '2', '3', '3.1']); // false '1.3' missing
sortAndCheckSequence(['1', '1.1', '1.1.1', '1.1.2', '1.2', '1.3', '1.4', '2', '2.1', '9', '3', '3.1']); //false '9' is not in sequence
```

Comment: This function does not returns anything? 
I want the function to simple return true if numbers are in sequence and has no duplicate or else false

Comment: My apologies, it would appear that the snippet editor's overzealous "tidy" function broke the code. It's fixed now.

Comment: No, sorry it still returns blank on console for every sample data

Comment: Well I don't know what to tell you – you can click the `Run code snippet` button and see it working; you can copy-paste the entire thing to your local console and run `sortAndCheckSequence(['1','1.1'])`. The code itself is less important than the algorithm, of course – is there any part of it that you find hard to follow?

Comment: Thanks now it's working!.. I'll test this on my actual code and if all is good I'll mark your answer correct.

Comment: Good to know. You can of course remove the `console.log(..)` output, or make better use of the specific validation messages as needed. Does this fully address your use case?